# Generating non duplicate permutation pairs of 2 lists in Java on the fly

Tags: java, permutation

I've been looking at a lot of different posts about permutations in Java, but none of them did fit my bill so I decided to post.

So I have 2 `List<Integer>`, and I need to generate all **permutation pairs** with **no duplicates** where one element of the pair is in the first list and the second one in the second list.

For example, if I have:

```
List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3});
List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {2, 3, 4});
```

Then I want in output:

```
(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 4)
```

Note that (3, 2) is not here since I already have (2, 3)

I couldn't find any library to do something even remotely close, I found that `guava` had something similar with `Permutations` but it seems to have been discontinued recently or something.

Also, I would like to not have to store the list in memory as it can be quite large, I only need to iterate on the pairs one at a time, so I'm trying to find ways to generate them **on the fly**. I was thinking to implement an `Iterable<Pair>` but I can't seem to be able to write anything that looks efficient.

If you know libraries that already do this kind of stuff that would be very helpful as well !

Comment: I don't think this is doable without storing some things in memory to establish which pairs have already been seen.  In any event, which Guava thing are you referring to?  I don't think we've "discontinued" anything along these lines...

Comment: I my be wrong but I think you mean sets, not Permutations. Permutations care about the order, so you can have the save values in different order, and they are not considered equivalent. Sets do not care about order, only about what is in them. Not sure if that will help you find a solution, but thought it may.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
class Pair {
    private int x, y;

    Pair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        int result = 1;
        result = 31 * result + x;
        result = 31 * result + y;
        return result;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)              return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Pair))   return false;
        Pair tmp = (Pair) obj;
        return (tmp.x == x && tmp.y == y) || (tmp.x == y && tmp.y == x);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }
}

class Testt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList( 1, 2, 3 );
        List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList( 2, 3, 4 );

        Set<Pair> set = new HashSet<Pair>();
        for (int i : l1)
            for (int j : l2)
                set.add(new Pair(i, j));

        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

Output

```
[(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (3,3), (3,4)]
```

Comment: That sounds pretty nice thanks, I didn't think in terms of sets... Just curious, why do you use a `LinkedHashSet` and not just a `HashSet`?

Comment: It should be `HashSet` I forgot to replace it back after testing different idea.